# big crash when i save images from viewpager to sdcard?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, sd-card, android-gallery

I have this code to save images from viewpager to sdcard but when i run it "Error during image saving" appears .
I read this : [How to save image from ViewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310447/how-to-save-image-from-viewpager)
and do all of the comments and every error gone and every thing is ok but when i run it "Error during image saving" appears .

Sdcard.java

```
package com.example.sdcard;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Sdcard extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Context mContext ;

    Button save;

    final File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Images/");
    boolean success = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sdcard);
        final Context mContext ;
        mContext=this;

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                final String fname = "StyleMe-" + n + ".png";

                myDir.mkdirs();

                File image = new File(myDir, fname);

                int currentItem =viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(adapter.mImages[currentItem]);
                Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

                // Encode the file as a PNG image.
                FileOutputStream outStream;
                try {

                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
                    /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success at /sdcard/Pictures/SexyImages",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
                        ("file://"
                                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

            }
        });

    }

    public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        public int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,

        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          Context context = Sdcard.this;
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
          imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
      }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and sdcard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl_view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bSave"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Save"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="0dp"
     />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

why this error appears ???? 
help me please

and it is logcat red lines :

```
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): Process: com.example.sdcard, PID: 1449
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=1449, uid=10075
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1461)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.example.sdcard.Sdcard$1.onClick(Sdcard.java:92)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-28 03:59:17.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): Process: com.example.sdcard, PID: 1498
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=1498, uid=10075
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1461)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at com.example.sdcard.Sdcard$1.onClick(Sdcard.java:92)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-28 04:00:36.556: E/AndroidRuntime(1498):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): Process: com.example.sdcard, PID: 1540
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=1540, uid=10075
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1461)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at com.example.sdcard.Sdcard$1.onClick(Sdcard.java:92)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-28 04:02:25.736: E/AndroidRuntime(1540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: no log is just guesswork

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial - @IFR answered

Answer (score 1):

Do you have set the permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=1498, uid=10075

```
public static boolean isSDCARDAvailable(){
   return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)? true :false;
}
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```